# three js delay on first load of mesh with large texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, game-engine

I am experiencing a delay of about 0.25 seconds when creating a specific mesh and adding it to a scene.  The mesh in question uses a 4096 x 4096 rgba texture and is contained by a simple 2 triangle square geometry created with:

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(this.w/1000*RESOLUTION,this.h/1000*RESOLUTION,1,1);
var customUniforms = {
    time: {type:"f",value:performance.now()/1000},
    tex: { type: "t", value: ResourceManager.get('explosion_spread').tex },
    a: { type: "f", value: this.a }
};
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({uniforms:customUniforms,vertexShader:ResourceManager.get('vert_anim'),fragmentShader:ResourceManager.get('frag_anim'),wireframe:false,transparent:true});
this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
scene.add(this.mesh);
```

There is only a lag the first time a mesh like this is added to the scene, all subsequent additions are smooth.  I have already used code similar to this to preload the textures:

```
ResourceManager.threeLoader.load(url,function(t){
    items[name].item.tex = t;
});
```

But it does not help.  Any one know how I can get rid of this initial lag?

Please note, that I already have a preloader in place, the game does not start until all the images, textures, ect have already been loaded.  And even then, the texture in question only gets used later on in the game.

Comment: This sounds like a network connection related issue.. especially the lag time looks like you are using https protocol?..

Comment: and it's even more probable because it appears to happen
only once and after that the server would use keep alive connection

Comment: Whats the point of the threeLoader.load then?  How do I preload the images in three js?